# PowerQuery - SQL data from List - Sort Order Issue

Tags: sql, excel, sorting, powerquery

I have an Excel workbook with a column of SKU codes. These codes are not in any logical sort order.
I'm using the SKU column to generate a list which is used by a SQL query to return the description for each SKU.
This is working, however the returned SQL results are sorted. Is there any way to do some kind of Table.Sort using the order in the original list?

Here is the current M code

```
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SKU"]}[Content],
    Column1 = Source[Column1],
    values = List.Transform(Column1, each Text.From(_)),
    valuesText = Text.Combine(values, "','"),
    query = "SELECT ITEMNO, [DESC] AS DESCRIPTION FROM DimItem_R WHERE ITEMNO IN ('" & valuesText & "')",
    target = Sql.Database("XXXXX", "XXXXX", [Query=query])
in
    target
```

Here is an example of the output.

[image]

SKU is the original list. As you can see ITEMNO and DESCRIPTION do not align with the list items

Comment: Add an index to the Source, later, merge the index and SKU back over target, expand the index, resort

Comment: Thanks. Would I need to convert the Source back to a table to be able to add the index?
If so is it better to do that after the lookup to SQL as I will loose the ability to combine the text in the query string without the list

Comment: Yes. Convert source to a table after the SQL then add index

Comment: I provided an example below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought an example might help

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SKU"]}[Content],
Column1 = Source[Column1],
values = List.Transform(Column1, each Text.From(_)),
valuesText = Text.Combine(values, "','"),
query = "SELECT ITEMNO, [DESC] AS DESCRIPTION FROM DimItem_R WHERE ITEMNO IN ('" & valuesText & "')",
target = Sql.Database("XXXXX", "XXXXX", [Query=query]),

sequence = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromList(values), "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(target, {"ITEMNO"}, sequence, {"Column1"}, "seq", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded seq" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "seq", {"Index"}, {"Index"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded seq",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}})
in #"Sorted Rows"

in target
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works as expected.
However being that the SKU and ITEMNO are unique in my tables I was able to do the merge on those columns which did not require the index.
But I do have another file which will certainly need your solution.